# Stable list set-difference in Dart

Tags: dart

We have two lists

```
List<String> list1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'blah', 'bee', 'fog'];
List<String> list2 = ['bee', 'bar'];
```

and we'd like to remove from the first the items in the second.

We can iterate, removing those in the second one by one

```
for (var v in list2) {
  list1.removeWhere((item) => item == v);
}
```

but that's silly. It'll take time proportional to the product of the length of the two lists.

We can convert to sets and use Dart's Set.difference(), then return a list.

```
n = (n.toSet().difference(m.toSet())).toList();
```

but we lose the order of the items in `list1`.

What's a good way for determining stable list set-difference in Dart?

Comment: Are you sure that your `Set.difference()` approach isn't stable?  `Set`'s default implementation is a `LinkedHashSet`, which preserves the original order, and I see no reason why `LinkedHashSet.difference` would change that order.

Comment: @jamesdlin  Good point... I'll need to check Dart's source. It's apparently all open, but I haven't been there yet. Still, julemand101 suggests a way that both avoids the conversion of `list1` to a `Set` and is clearly stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to convert `list2` into a `Set` to make it more efficient to ask if an element from `list1` is part of `list2`. We can then use `removeWhere` to remove elements from `list1`:

```
void main() {
  List<String> list1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'blah', 'bee', 'fog'];
  List<String> list2 = ['bee', 'bar'];
  
  list1.removeWhere(list2.toSet().contains);
  print(list1); // [foo, blah, fog]
}
```

Comment: Ah... clever... I think that does it...  but may I edit to replace "to just convert `list2`" with "to convert just `list2`"?

Comment: Fixed my wording. :)